# Any cases when an object does not traverse its prototype chain to get value?

Tags: javascript, prototype, proto, object-create, prototype-chain

As we know, when we try to access an object's property it first check's if the object has its own property. If it does not find, it traverses the prototype and checks, and so on up the prototype chain.

Coming to the question, please check the below code snippet(http://jsbin.com/mabajidoti/edit?js,console)

```
function CT() {}
CT.prototype.myValue = 4;
var myObj = Object.create(CT);

console.log(myObj.myValue);          //logs undefined
console.log(myObj.prototype.myValue) //logs 4
```

From the above snippet, the first console.log statement, myObj.myValue is returning undefined even though myValue is available in its prototype(2nd console.log statement)? Shouldn't it have traversed the prototype chain to fetch the myValue's value?

Comment: `CT.prototype` is used as prototype of new instances of `CT`. `Object.create(CT);` creates a new object with `CT` itself as its prototype. If you wanted `CT.prototype` to be the prototype, you'd have to call `Object.create(CT.prototype)`.

Comment: *"Any cases when an object does not traverse its prototype chain to get value?"* Nope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have confused [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) with calling a constructor function via the [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).

If you'd said:

```
var myObj = new CT();
```

*then* your `myObj` would be linked to the `CT.prototype` and thus `myObj.myValue` would be `4`.

But by using `Object.create(CT)` you've created a new object whose prototype is the `CT` function itself. So `CT.prototype` is *not* part of your new object's prototype chain. Note that `CT.prototype` isn't in `CT`'s prototype chain, rather, it specifies the object that will be the prototype for things created with `new CT()`.

A more correct use of `Object.create()` to allow access to a `myValue` property from the prototype would be:

```js
var CT = {
  myValue : 4
};
var myObj = Object.create(CT);
console.log(myObj.myValue);          //logs 4
```

Or with your existing `CT()` function and `CT.prototype` you could say:

```
myObj = Object.create(CT.prototype);
```

Answer (score 0):

prototype is instance variable, you can access prototype with obj.prototypeName when you create obj with `new Obj()`

first see Array

```
Array.forEach
// undefined

Array.prototype.forEach
// ƒ forEach() { [native code] }

new Array().forEach
// ƒ forEach() { [native code] }

[].forEach
// ƒ forEach() { [native code] }
```

see your CT class

```
function CT() {}
CT.prototype.myValue = 4;
var ct1 = new CT();
var ct2 = new CT();

ct1.myValue = 100;

console.log(ct1.myValue); //logs 100
console.log(ct2.myValue); //logs 4
```